# $_POST does not detect the formData passed from ajax

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, yii, redux-api-middleware

Using `redux-api-middleware` which works similarly to `axios` and `jquery.ajax`, I passed a formData which is a mixture of an image and other form values as you can see on this image: [image]

The problem I have is that after successfully calling the API via a POST request, the PHP `$_POST` object is null though there was an actual POST request happening. This is my code snippet:

```
import { CALL_API } from "redux-api-middleware";

export function createTestAnnouncement(data) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { auth: { oauthToken, oauthTokenSecret } } = getState();

    const formData = new FormData();

    Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      if (key === 'image') {
        formData.append(key, value);
      } else {
        formData.set(key, value);
      }
    });

    return dispatch({
      [CALL_API]: {
        endpoint: "/api/test-announcements",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          'xoauthtoken': oauthToken,
          'xoauthtokensecret': oauthTokenSecret,
        },
        body: formData,
        types: [CREATE_TEST_ANNOUNCEMENTS, CREATE_TEST_ANNOUNCEMENTS_SUCCESS, CREATE_TEST_ANNOUNCEMENTS_FAILURE]
      }
    })
  }
}
```

How will be able to get values from the `$_POST` object? Did I use the `FormData` object correctly?

EDIT: My Controller is just this, PS: I am sure this working because this is working on a plain `application/json` request

```
use api\controllers\BaseController;
use model\Operations\TestAnnouncements\TestAnnouncementOperation;
use model\DB\TestAnnouncement;

class IndexController extends BaseController
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        var_dump($_POST);
        // Commented this out because the payload is not JSON
        // $request = \Yii::app()->request;

        // $op = new TestAnnouncementOperation();
        // $op->topic = $request->getJSON('topic');
        ...
    }
...
```

I always get a NULL on my var_dump. While using postman and passing form-data on the body generates me a value on my $_POST.

Comment: There is no PHP code.

Comment: Where is your server side of code? Did it works properly? If you send a post request using tool such as  postman or curl, did your php server get the data?

Comment: I tried using postman, the $_POST object from the API was not null but when the request is from my JS app, it's NULL.

Comment: If you are using Yii framework to do rest, you should use their request class to obtain params from client better than raw code. eg. `$arrival = yii::$app->request->post('arrival');`. then try and test with your postman if you can get payload from postman request. I assume that you have a problem with ` redux-api-middleware` module. you can check this 'https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-multipartformdataparser' also.

Comment: @SenSokha thank you for the answer sir but I'm actually using Yii 1.. I'll have to include it on the tags.

Comment: @SenSokha I actually used this:

`$yii::$app()->request->getPost('topic') //topic is the payload from JS`, it returned to NULL while it looks good on PostMan. The primary reason why I didn't post the PHP code to this at first because I was actually thinking there is no problem with the PHP code. I wanted people to examine if there is something wrong with my JS code.

Comment: Check what Content-Type header actually gets send, in your browser dev tools network panel.

Comment: hello @04FS, it's multipart/form-data with a boundary that's automatically added by the browser.

Comment: Sounds like that is as it should be then. Does it show the individual parameters as well in there? (Section titled “Form Data” in Chrome dev tools.)

Comment: Yes! Form data is there, and that's the puzzling thing..

Answer (score 0):

you can check if the variable is set or not using...

```
if(!isset($_POST["ur_varible_name_from_html_form"]))
{

  echo "error";
}
```

Comment: Edited my question

Answer (score 0):

> You can see `redux-api-middleware` repo on github, issues [#125](https://github.com/agraboso/redux-api-middleware/issues/125). They already have resolved and given example [CALL_API] and [RSAA] with from data.